# The data in the array does not change after the remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Basically my code works like that:

1* Send the first line.
2* Get the response and sent it back.
3* remove one line and check the next line which will be the first line.

However in my code the data does not change at all in the whole process it checks only the first line again and again this is the code that i tried:

```
var resource = $('#resource').val().replace(/[\n\r](?!\w)/gi, "").split("\n");  

$.each(resource , function() {
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url :'curl_check.php',
    data: 'email='+resource[0],
    success: function(data) {
      alert(resource);
      resource.splice(0, 1);
      $('#resource').val(resource.join("\n"))
    }   
  });
});
```

Basically even the line is removed from the text-area the values still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is weird, I think you hit issue because you 'strip' the `resource` array in the success callback which is async, that means you are always sending the first entry of the array in the loop...

A 'hack' that you can try to proof this is to add `async: false` to the ajax parameter, although that's not quite the right way to really do this..

Comment: yes because if i don't use it inside success, the lines will be deleted all, and after that the response start to come, what i want as i said i want to delete line by line so, CHeck and delete. check and delete like that

Comment: splicing the array inside a loop is already freaky, if you really need to do it 1 by 1, I suggest you make another for loop and make the request `async: false` as I suggested. i.e.
var length = resource.length;
` for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
      $.ajax({
           ........
           async: false,
           .......
       });
 }

Comment: Although again, I don't think it's a good way to do it...maybe you can explain what you really want to do

Comment: You are great man no one could solve it only you lol, yes that's what i wanted when i made the asyc false it works, i wanted to check and remove check and remove check and remove. however when the asyc was true all the lines are deleted at the same time and after that the responses start coming at once.

Comment: I think you can optimize that in some ways...but anyway, glad that it helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you're stripping out the the newlines, and line-feed characters with your regex on line 1, but then you are attempting to perform a split(\n). This split will fail because you have just removed the newlines with nothing.